# PYQT5: How to link the 3 pushbottons with 3 .py

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

How to use pyqtSlot to connect the QMainWindow with 3 QtWidgets?

I wanna to use 3 buttons to switch 3 screen for each .py files.

The UiPE.py file for the 3 pushbutton to switch 3 screens of .py file.

```
#=============
**UiPE.py**
#=============    
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Module implementing PB01.
"""

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from Ui_UiPE import Ui_MainWindow


class PB01(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    Class documentation goes here.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        Constructor

        @param parent reference to the parent widget
        @type QWidget
        """
        super(PB01, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_PBtn1PE_clicked(self):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    # TODO: not implemented yet
    #raise NotImplementedError

@pyqtSlot()
def on_PBtn2LC_clicked(self):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    # TODO: not implemented yet
    raise NotImplementedError

@pyqtSlot()
def on_PBtn3PP_clicked(self):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    # TODO: not implemented yet
    raise NotImplementedError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FormPE = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_FormPE()
    ui.setupUi(FormPE)
    FormPE.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ui_UiPE.py

```
#=============
**Ui_UiPE.py**
#=============
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

/*Form implementation generated from reading ui file
 '..\PyQt5\eee\UiPE.ui'*/
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(960, 736)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("border-image:\ 
        url(:/ME/images/Main.jpg);")

        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 500))
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.PBtn1PE = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.PBtn1PE.setEnabled(True)
        self.PBtn1PE.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 400, 150, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.PBtn1PE.setFont(font)
        self.PBtn1PE.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: \
        red;border-image: url();")

        self.PBtn1PE.setText("PE")
        self.PBtn1PE.setDefault(False)
        self.PBtn1PE.setObjectName("PBtn1PE")

        self.PBtn2LC = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.PBtn2LC.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 400, 150, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.PBtn2LC.setFont(font)
        self.PBtn2LC.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: \
        yellow;border-image: url();")

        self.PBtn2LC.setObjectName("PBtn2LC")

        self.PBtn3PP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.PBtn3PP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 400, 150, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.PBtn3PP.setFont(font)
        self.PBtn3PP.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.PBtn3PP.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: \
        rgb(0, 162, 232);;border-image: url();")

        self.PBtn3PP.setObjectName("PBtn3PP")

        self.BtnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.BtnClose.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 40, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.BtnClose.setFont(font)
        self.BtnClose.setWhatsThis("")
        self.BtnClose.setAccessibleName("")
        self.BtnClose.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.BtnClose.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: red;\
        border-image: url();")

        self.BtnClose.setText("Exit")
        self.BtnClose.setObjectName("BtnClose")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.PBtn1PE.released.connect(MainWindow.show)
        self.BtnClose.clicked.connect(self.frame.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.PBtn1PE, self.PBtn2LC)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.PBtn2LC, self.PBtn3PP)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.PBtn2LC.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LC"))
        self.PBtn3PP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PP"))

#import MainE_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ui_UiPE1.py

```
/*=============
#**Ui_UiPE1.py**, **Ui_UiLC.py** and **Ui_UiPP.py** is same script for 
#differet function.
=============*/
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file \
#'C:\Users\ST3C_01\PyQt5\eee\UiPE1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_FormPE(object):
    def setupUi(self, FormPE):
        FormPE.setObjectName("FormPE")
        FormPE.resize(960, 500)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        FormPE.setFont(font)
        FormPE.setStyleSheet("border-image:\ 
        url(:/myframe/images/PresidentElection.jpg);")

        self.PEBtn1B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn1B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 420, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn1B.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn1B.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn1B.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn1B.setText("  Decrease")
        self.PEBtn1B.setObjectName("PEBtn1B")

        self.PEBtn1A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn1A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 30, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn1A.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn1A.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn1A.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn1A.setText("  Increase")
        self.PEBtn1A.setObjectName("PEBtn1A")

        self.PEBtn2A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn2A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 30, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn2A.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn2A.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn2A.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn2A.setText("  Increase")
        self.PEBtn2A.setObjectName("PEBtn2A")

        self.PEBtn3A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn3A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 30, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn3A.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn3A.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn3A.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn3A.setText("  Increase")
        self.PEBtn3A.setObjectName("PEBtn3A")

        self.PEBtn2B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn2B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 420, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn2B.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn2B.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn2B.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn2B.setText("  Decrease")
        self.PEBtn2B.setObjectName("PEBtn2B")

        self.PEBtn3B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn3B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 420, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn3B.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn3B.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn3B.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn3B.setText("  Decrease")
        self.PEBtn3B.setObjectName("PEBtn3B")

        self.retranslateUi(FormPE)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FormPE)

    def retranslateUi(self, FormPE):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FormPE.setWindowTitle(_translate("FormPE", "Form"))

#import PE_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FormPE = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_FormPE()
    ui.setupUi(FormPE)
    FormPE.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above is my example.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I try to follow the post format, but the code have some mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand what you mean with "use 3 buttons to switch 3 screen". What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: musicamante, I try to follow the Eric6 to make the UiPE.py file, but google many files, still do not understand how to write it, it not like the C language. I'm sorry, I'm just the Python Beginer.

Comment: You've not answered my question: what are you trying to do?

Comment: musicamante, because I want to use the Ui_UiPE1.py to connect the Microchip EVM board via USB CDC from NB/Raspberry/FPGA board.

Comment: **musicamante**, Frankly to say, Our God ask me; try to be the the Technology, Public welfare, President of public servant in next year, to help our people and country, so I develop one system now. They waste too much of our country's resources and the people's tax money, and money goes into the pockets of their political groups, and the people are getting poorer. I'm Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
#        MainWindow.resize(960, 536)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(960, 470)                                                 # +
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
#        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(Ok.png);")
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")                                 # +++
        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("#centralWidget {border-image: url(Ok.png);}")   # +++

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 960, 500))
        self.frame.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        self.PBtn1PE = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.PBtn1PE.setEnabled(True)
        self.PBtn1PE.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 400, 150, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.PBtn1PE.setFont(font)
        self.PBtn1PE.setStyleSheet("""
            border: 2px groove gray;
            border-radius: 10px; 
            padding: 2px 4px;
            background-color: red;
        """)
        self.PBtn1PE.setText("PE")
        self.PBtn1PE.setDefault(False)
        self.PBtn1PE.setObjectName("PBtn1PE")

        self.PBtn2LC = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.PBtn2LC.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 400, 150, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.PBtn2LC.setFont(font)
        self.PBtn2LC.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: yellow;")
        self.PBtn2LC.setObjectName("PBtn2LC")

        self.PBtn3PP = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.PBtn3PP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 400, 150, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.PBtn3PP.setFont(font)
        self.PBtn3PP.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.PBtn3PP.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);")
        self.PBtn3PP.setObjectName("PBtn3PP")

        self.BtnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.BtnClose.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(860, 40, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.BtnClose.setFont(font)
        self.BtnClose.setWhatsThis("")
        self.BtnClose.setAccessibleName("")
        self.BtnClose.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.BtnClose.setStyleSheet("border:2px groove gray;\
        border-radius:10px;padding:2px 4px;background-color: red;")
        self.BtnClose.setText("Exit")
        self.BtnClose.setObjectName("BtnClose")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.PBtn1PE.released.connect(MainWindow.show)
        self.BtnClose.clicked.connect(self.frame.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.PBtn1PE, self.PBtn2LC)
        MainWindow.setTabOrder(self.PBtn2LC, self.PBtn3PP)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.PBtn2LC.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LC"))
        self.PBtn3PP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PP"))


class Ui_FormPE(object):
    def setupUi(self, FormPE):
        FormPE.setObjectName("FormPE")
        FormPE.resize(960, 500)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        FormPE.setFont(font)
        FormPE.setStyleSheet("#FormPE {border-image: url(im.png);}")   # + #FormPE

        self.PEBtn1B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn1B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 420, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn1B.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)                                          # 16
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn1B.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn1B.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn1B.setText(" Decrease ")                             # " Decrease "
        self.PEBtn1B.setObjectName("PEBtn1B")

        self.PEBtn1A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn1A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 30, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn1A.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn1A.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn1A.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn1A.setText(" Increase ")
        self.PEBtn1A.setObjectName("PEBtn1A")

        self.PEBtn2A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn2A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 30, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn2A.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn2A.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn2A.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn2A.setText(" Increase ")
        self.PEBtn2A.setObjectName("PEBtn2A")

        self.PEBtn3A = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn3A.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 30, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn3A.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn3A.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn3A.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn3A.setText(" Increase ")
        self.PEBtn3A.setObjectName("PEBtn3A")

        self.PEBtn2B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn2B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 420, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn2B.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn2B.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn2B.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn2B.setText(" Decrease ")
        self.PEBtn2B.setObjectName("PEBtn2B")

        self.PEBtn3B = QtWidgets.QPushButton(FormPE)
        self.PEBtn3B.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(830, 420, 111, 40))
        self.PEBtn3B.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MingLi")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.PEBtn3B.setFont(font)
        self.PEBtn3B.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.PEBtn3B.setText(" Decrease ")
        self.PEBtn3B.setObjectName("PEBtn3B")

        self.retranslateUi(FormPE)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FormPE)

    def retranslateUi(self, FormPE):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FormPE.setWindowTitle(_translate("FormPE", "Form"))


class PB01(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PB01, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_PBtn1PE_clicked(self):
        print("on_PBtn1PE_clicked")

        self.FormPE = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_FormPE()
        ui.setupUi(self.FormPE)
        self.FormPE.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_PBtn2LC_clicked(self):
        print("on_PBtn2LC_clicked")

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_PBtn3PP_clicked(self):
        print("on_PBtn3PP_clicked")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = PB01()                                                # +++
    w.show()                                                  # +++

#    FormPE = QtWidgets.QWidget()
#    ui = Ui_FormPE()
#    ui.setupUi(FormPE)
#    FormPE.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: S. Nick, Ha ha, Many thanks you! Because you combine all in one file, It's great. But my Ui_UiPE1.py, Ui_UiLC.py and Ui_UiPP.py files, they have to add different "USB communications device class" function for calculation, reception, transmission.

Many thanks you! You are Top guy!